# Android : two TextView, Two fonts , only one applied

Tags: android

Pretty weird problem,
And I don't find anything to explain why it is happening.
I have two very classic textViews, and I want to apply two different fonts to each textViews. 
'Title' in regular, 'Description' in light. 
The problem is that it takes only the first one and applies it to both of them.
Explanation : If I put medium or light to the first, both of the textviews will have the same font, whatever font I put for the second one.
Here is my xml :

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:visibility="gone" />
```

Result being both of them in medium. (edit : the visibility of the 2nd textView is changed programaticly in the code)

And I tried to do it programaticly :

```
final TextView tv_title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        if (tv_title != null) {
            tv_title.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-medium", Typeface.NORMAL));
        }
final TextView tv_subTitleription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
            if (tv_subTitleription != null) {
 tv_subTitleription.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL));
                }
```

I am seriously amazed by this weird attitude. Does anyone has any idea why it is not applying differents fonts to each?

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you sure both fonts exist?  My rule of thumb with android is any font I don't have the .ttf for myself is not likely to work.

Comment: I am sure, If i put one in first it works, same for the other. And I use those fonts elsewhere in the app and it is working like a charm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend for you create custom TextView with support fonts.
You can use my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet; 
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TypefaceTextView extends TextView {

public TypefaceTextView(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TypefaceTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initAttribute(attrs);
}

public TypefaceTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
        final int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initAttribute(attrs);
}

public void initAttribute(final AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray typedArray = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.TypefaceTextView,
            0, 0);

    try {
        switch (typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.TypefaceTextView_typeface, 0)) {
        case 0:
            setTypeface(FontUtils.getFirstFont(getContext()));
            break;
        case 1:
            setTypeface(FontUtils.getSecordFont(getContext()));
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    } finally {
        typedArray.recycle();
    }
  }
}
```

Add attrs.xml file to the values folder with following content :

```
<declare-styleable name="TypefaceTextView">
    <attr name="typeface" format="enum">
        <enum name="name_typeface_1" value="0"/>
        <enum name="name_typeface_2" value="1"/>
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

After this operation you can add typeface to textView in the xml file, for example:

```
<com.example.project.TypefaceTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTypeface"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:typeface="name_typeface_1"/>
```

Code for FontUtils:

```
public class FontUtils {

private static final String FONT_1_PATH =  "fonts/font1.ttf";

private static final String FONT_2_PATH = "fonts/font1.TTF";

public static Typeface getFirstFont(Context context) {
    return getFont(context, FONT_1_PATH);
}

public static Typeface getSecordFont(Context context) {
    return getFont(context, FONT_2_PATH);
}

private static Typeface getFont(Context context, String name) {
    return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), name);
 }
}
```

I think it is flexible solution, because you may be need more one font in the future.

Comment: If you need help, call me in the viber or telegram +380971493220 @hermance